# Loop with native promises;

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to make an asynchronous loop with native [ES6 promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) It *kind of* works, but incorrectly. I suppose I made a huge mistake somewhere and I need someone to tell me where it is and how it's done correctly

```
var i = 0;

//creates sample resolver
function payloadGenerator(){
    return function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            i++;
            resolve();
        }, 300)
    }
}

// creates resolver that fulfills the promise if condition is false, otherwise rejects the promise.
// Used only for routing purpose
function controller(condition){
    return function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('i =', i);
        condition ? reject('fin') : resolve();
    }
}

// creates resolver that ties payload and controller together
// When controller rejects its promise, main fulfills its thus exiting the loop
function main(){
    return function(resolve, reject) {
        return new Promise(payloadGenerator())
            .then(function(){
                return new Promise(controller(i>6))
            })
            .then(main(),function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                resolve(err)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err , 'caught');
                resolve(err)
            })
    }
}


new Promise(main())
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('caught', err);
    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log('exit');
        process.exit()
    });
```

Now the output:

```
/usr/local/bin/iojs test.js
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
fin
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
error: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
caught [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
exit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The good part: it reaches the end.

The bad part: it catches some errors and I don't know why.

Comment: Regardless of libraries being used the way you're using promises is _really_ strange. What is your end goal here? You want to implement a "while" with promises?

Comment: `.then(main(),function (err) {`. When is the `main()` doing there?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah I know. I'm new to promises and trying to figure out how they work. Yes, it's a while loop; JLRishe: It's supposed to count to 7 and do not produce any errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any helper function with promise looping I have seen actually made it much worse than what you can do out of the box with recursion.

It is a little nicer with `.thenReturn` but yeah:

```
function readFile(index) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Read file number " + (index +1));
            resolve();
        }, 500);
    });
}

// The loop initialization
Promise.resolve(0).then(function loop(i) {
    // The loop check
    if (i < len) {              // The post iteration increment
        return readFile(i).thenReturn(i + 1).then(loop);
    }
}).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("error", e);
});
```

See it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fd1wc1ra/

This is pretty much exactly equivalent to:

```
try {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        readFile(i);
    }
    console.log("done");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("error", e);
}
```

---

If you wanted to do nested loops it is exactly the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/fd1wc1ra/1/

```
function printItem(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Item " + item);
            resolve();
        }, 500);
    });
}

var mdArray = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
Promise.resolve(0).then(function loop(i) {
    if (i < mdArray.length) {
        var array = mdArray[i];
        return Promise.resolve(0).then(function innerLoop(j) {
            if (j < array.length) {
                var item = array[j];
                return printItem(item).thenReturn(j + 1).then(innerLoop);
            }
        }).thenReturn(i + 1).then(loop);
    }
}).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("error", e);
});
```

Comment: Magnificent, thank you! Nice trick with `thenReturn`.  One remark: your code here is different from code on jsfiddle, I was confused at first. jsfiddle version worked for me since iojs' promise implementation doesn't have `thenReturn`.

Comment: @amdc `thenReturn` is from bluebird but can be implemented on native promises as shown in the jsifddle.

Comment: Works very well! I want to be able to do like 5 loops at the same time and when one of those is done, go on with the 6th and so on until the array is done. Any suggestions? Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/q/36664272/1760313

Answer (score 2):

If all you're trying to do is count to 7 with promises, then this will do it:

```
function f(p, i) {
  return p.then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(r) { return setTimeout(r, 300); });
  })
  .then(function() { console.log(i); });
}

var p = Promise.resolve();
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  p = f(p, i);
}
p.then(function() { console.log('fin'); })
 .catch(function(e) { console.log(e.message); });
```

Looping with promises is hard, because it's almost impossible not to fall into JavaScript's [closures in a loop trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), but it is doable. The above works because it pushes all use of .then() into a sub-function `f` of the loop (i.e. away from the loop).

A safer solution, that I use, is to forgo loops altogether and seek out patterns like `forEach` and `reduce` whenever I can, because they effectively force the sub-function on you:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].reduce(f, Promise.resolve())
.then(function() { console.log('fin'); })
.catch(function(e) { console.log(e.message); });
```

here `f` is the same function as above. [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/0phjhmcc).

**Update:** [In ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36853579/918910) you can also use `for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++)` to avoid the "closures in a loop" trap without pushing code into a sub-function `f`.

**PS:** The mistake in your example is `.then(main(),` - it needs to be `.then(function() { return new Promise(main()); },` but really, I think you're using the pattern wrong. `main()` should **return** a promise, not be wrapped by one.

Comment: This is a for loop - I think OP was going for a `while` which would not work with thenable chaining since you would not know how much chaining you need in advance.

Comment: Maybe the OP meant that the condition depended on the previous steps having executed? If so, then yes recursion would be needed. In any case, using a while-loop instead of for-loop, doesn't solve this, or mean that. I've changed the for-loop to a while-loop to show that.  The OP said in a comment he was trying to count to 7 with promises, and asked someone to point out his mistake, which I hope I did.

Comment: Of course changing the for loop to another synchronous looping construct wouldn't help - I meant that conceptually the number of iterations depends on previous state.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum for loops are fine too.  it's always good to know how  to make it in different ways, thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging `err.stack` instead of just `err` when catching promise errors.

In this case, it looks like `resolve` and `reject` are not defined within the anonymous function that gets return from `main` after the initial iteration is complete. I can't totally follow your control flow, but that seems to make sense - after the 7 iterations are complete, there should no longer be any new promises. However, it seems like the code is still trying to run like there are more promises to resolve.

Edit: This is the problem `.then(main(),function (err) {`. Invoking `main` on its own will cause `resolve` and `reject` inside the anonymous function to be undefined. From the way I read it, `main` can only be invoked as an argument to the `Promise` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around for various solutions too and couldn't find one that satisfied me, so I ended up creating my own. Here it is in case it's useful to someone else:

The idea is to create an array of promise generators and to give this array to a helper function that's going to execute the promises one after another.

In my case the helper function is simply this:

```
function promiseChain(chain) {
    let output = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); });
    for (let i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
        let f = chain[i];
        output = output.then(f);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then, for example, to load multiple URLs one after another, the code would be like this:

```
// First build the array of promise generators:

let urls = [......];
let chain = [];
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    chain.push(() => {
        return fetch(urls[i]);
    });
}

// Then execute the promises one after another:

promiseChain(chain).then(() => {
    console.info('All done');
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that it creates code that's relatively close to a regular for loop, and with minimal indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and tried the accepted answer, but I was having a problem with the order of operations. `Promise.all` is the solution.

```
function work(context) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    operation(context)
      .then(result => resolve(result)
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

Promise
  .all(arrayOfContext.map(context => work(context)))
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```