# Return after loop using JS Promises

Tags: javascript, foreach, es6-promise

I have an ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax(myAPI).done(parse(response));
```

Below is the success callback function to a previous API request:

```
parse(response) {
    let TreeObj= { 'Trees' : [] };

    response.ClassificationIds.forEach(classificationObj => {
        $.get('myAPI/' + classificationObj)
            .then((classification) => {
                TreeObj.Trees.push(classification);
            });
    });

    return TreeObj;
}
```

I'd like to return the TreeObj only after the `forEach` loop is finished looping. I'd like to do this by using promises, in particular `$.Deferred` by the jQuery library. How do I do this?

Comment: For clarification, are you using a library? Or just native promises?

Comment: jQuery's $.Deferred is preferred, but I'm interested in seeing native promises

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6538470/218196 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134271/loop-with-native-promises this may help you

Comment: @iggy2012: For native promises, use `Promise.all`