# How to use promise with for loop and $.get request?

Tags: javascript

This is my first time using promises so i'm sure there are pretty dumb mistakes here. What im trying to do, is send a http request thats in a for loop.

When doing this without the promise, i can run this loop fine and everything works properly. however, when I do this with the promise, it only returns one object (should be multiple, as its sending multiple requests)

This is my code

```
function run(o,initialvalue){
        const test = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
            const collectionCountUrl = 'https://x.io/rpc/Query?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22collectionSymbol%22%3A%22'+o.name+'%22%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22takerAmount%22%3A1%2C%22createdAt%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22%24skip%22%3A'+initialvalue+'%2C%22%24limit%22%3A500%7D'
            promises = []
            for(i=0; i < o.count(/*in this case 60, so 3 requests*/); i+= 20){
                $.get(collectionCountUrl).success(resolve).fail(reject) // This should be sending multiple of the requests above, correct? ^
            }
        })
    
        test.then(function(data){
            console.log(data) // this should return the data from each request? im not sure
        })
    }
```

I've tried to check out this post to see if I was setting up the for loop wrong but I dont think I am.
[Promise for-loop with Ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664272/promise-for-loop-with-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 0):

One promise is for a single result. You have to wrap a each request in a seperate promise (move the constructor call into the loop), and store the promises in an array.

Then, you can use aggregator methods like `Promise.all` (others being `Promise.allSettled`, `Promise.race` and `Promise.any`) to get a single promise of an array of results, that you can wait for.

Like this:

```
function run(o,initialvalue){
    const collectionCountUrl = 'https://x.io/rpc/Query?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22collectionSymbol%22%3A%22'+o.name+'%22%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22takerAmount%22%3A1%2C%22createdAt%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22%24skip%22%3A'+initialvalue+'%2C%22%24limit%22%3A500%7D'
    const promises = []
//  ^^^^^----+--- don't forget to declare all your variables
//      vvv--+
    for(let i=0; i < o.count(/*in this case 60, so 3 requests*/); i+= 20){
        promises.push(new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
            $.get(collectionCountUrl).success(resolve).fail(reject) 
        }))
    }
    
    //You've got an array of promises, let's convert it to a single one that resolves when everything's done:
    const test = Promise.all(promises)

    test.then(function(data){
        //This will run when all the requests have succeeded
        //`data` is an array of results
        console.log(data) 
    })
}
```

This will work, but there's an even better way!

jQuery's `$.Deferred` objects (like the one you're getting from `$.get`) also have a `.then()` method like promises do, and while it's not a *real* promise, you can use it like if it was. Such objects are called *`then`ables*.

So, instead of this thing...

```
promises.push(new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    $.get(collectionCountUrl).success(resolve).fail(reject) 
}))
```

...you can just do this:

```
promises.push( $.get(collectionCountUrl) )
```

So, here's the final code:

```
function run(o,initialvalue){
    const collectionCountUrl = 'https://x.io/rpc/Query?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22collectionSymbol%22%3A%22'+o.name+'%22%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22takerAmount%22%3A1%2C%22createdAt%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22%24skip%22%3A'+initialvalue+'%2C%22%24limit%22%3A500%7D'
    const promises = []
    for(let i=0; i < o.count(/*in this case 60, so 3 requests*/); i+= 20){
        promises.push( $.get(collectionCountUrl) )
    }
    
    //You've got an array of promises, let's convert it to a single one that resolves when everything's done:
    const test = Promise.all(promises)

    test.then(function(data){
        //This will run when all the requests have succeeded
        //`data` is an array of results
        console.log(data) 
    })
}
```