# Why is let slower than var in a for loop in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8

I have written a very simple benchmark:

```
console.time('var');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('var')


console.time('let');
for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('let')
```

If you're running Chrome, you can try it here (since NodeJS and Chrome use the same JavaScript engine, albeit usually slightly different versions):

```js
// Since Node runs code in a function wrapper with a different
// `this` than global code, do that:
(function() {
  console.time('var');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('var')


  console.time('let');
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
  console.timeEnd('let')
}).call({});
```

And the results amaze me:

```
var: 89.162ms
let: 320.473ms
```

I have tested it in Node 4.0.0 && 5.0.0 && 6.0.0 and the proportion between `var` and `let` is the same for each node version.

Could someone please explain to me what is the reason behid this seemingly odd behaviour?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114723/discussion-on-question-by-jan-osch-why-is-let-slower-than-var-in-a-for-loop-in-n).

Comment: Issue on the V8 bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4762&q=let%20label%3APerformance%20&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20HW%20OS%20Component%20Stars

Comment: Yes, testing in Chrome 60 this issue seems to solved in Chrome so it should be solved in node soon. It was already solved in SpiderMonkey. It has yet to be solved for Safari Nitro as of May 9th 2017

Comment: In the meantime, let is faster in Chrome, on Node, even in IE 11.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sub>**A note from the future**: these historical performance differences are no longer accurate or relevant, as modern engines can optimize `let` semantics by using `var` semantics when there are no observable differences in behavior. When there *are* observable differences, using the correct semantics makes little difference in performance since the relevant code is already asynchronous in nature.</sub>

Based on the difference between the mechanics of `var` vs. `let`, this discrepancy in runtime is due to the fact that `var` exists in the entire block scope of the anonymous function while `let` exists only within the loop and must be re-declared for each iteration.<sup>* see below</sup> Here's an example demonstrating this point:

```js
(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`i: ${i} seconds`);
    }, i * 1000);
  }
  // 5, 5, 5, 5, 5


  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`j: ${j} seconds`);
    }, 5000 + j * 1000);
  }
  // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}());
```

Notice that the `i` is shared across all iterations of the loop while `let` is not. Based on your benchmark, it appears that node.js just hasn't optimized scoping rules for `let` since it's much more recent and complicated than `var` is.

#### Elaboration

Here's a little layman explanation of `let` in `for` loops, for those who don't care to look into the admittedly dense specs, but are curious how `let` is re-declared for each iteration while still maintaining continuity.

> But `let` can't possibly be re-declared for each iteration, because if you change it inside the loop, it propagates to the next iteration!

First here's an example that almost appears to validate this potential counter-argument:

```js
(function() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    j++; // see how it skips 0, 2, and 4!?!?
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`j: ${j} seconds`);
    }, j * 1000);
  }
}());
```

You are partially right, in that the changes respect the continuity of `j`. However, it is still re-declared for each iteration, as demonstrated by Babel:

```js
"use strict";

(function () {
  var _loop = function _loop(_j) {
    _j++; // here's the change inside the new scope
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("j: " + _j + " seconds");
    }, _j * 1000);
    j = _j; // here's the change being propagated back to maintain continuity
  };

  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    _loop(j);
  }
})();
```

---

[Derek Ziemba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2651894/derek-ziemba) brings up [an interesting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792934/why-is-let-slower-than-var-in-a-for-loop-in-nodejs/37793317#comment68079649_37793317):

> Internet Explorer 14.14393 doesn't seem to have these [performance] issues.

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer [incorrectly implemented `let` syntax by essentially using the simpler `var` semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#browser_compatibility), so comparing its performance is a moot point:

> In Internet Explorer, `let` within a `for` loop initializer does not create a separate variable for each loop iteration as defined by ES2015. Instead, it behaves as though the loop were wrapped in a scoping block with the `let` immediately before the loop.

---

***** [This transpiled version](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&code=for%20(let%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%205%3B%20j%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20setTimeout(function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60j%3A%20%24%7Bj%7D%20seconds%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%205000%20%2B%20j%20*%201000)%3B%0D%0A%7D) on Babel's REPL demonstrates what happens when you declare a `let` variable in a `for` loop. A new declarative environment is created to hold that variable ([details here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation)), and then **for each loop iteration** *another* declarative environment is created to hold a per-iteration copy of the variable; each iteration's copy is initialized from the previous one's value ([details here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-forbodyevaluation)), but they're separate variables, as proven by the values output within each closure.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts your answer proves a different thing: that a variable declared with `var` remains in global scope: see `https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let-scoped_variables_in_for_loops`

Comment: @JanOsch: No, look closely at his `j` example and what it outputs. It's fascinating. [Here's Babel's transpilation of a simplified version.](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=for%20(let%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%205%3B%20%2B%2Bj)%20%7B%0A%20%20setTimeout(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(j)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%7D) There are two aspects to the variable, one of which is maintained across loops, the other (which we see in the body) which is created each time.

Comment: @JanOsch: If you're referring to *"...`var` exists in the entire block scope"*, I think by "block" he meant the "enclosing" scope of the block. The wording could be improved.

Comment: @squint wording improved.

Comment: For anyone curious, see also the [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612/1048572)

Comment: Internet Explorer 14.14393 doesn't seem to have these issues.  It's 3x faster than Chrome 54 when looping with 'let', and 175% faster looping in general.  http://jsbench.github.io/#e86c06909d7eedd18f8b9bac101e9d6d

Comment: @DerekZiemba long overdue, but see my updated answer for an explanation. tl;dr IE is wrong (what a surprise)

Answer (score 4):

For this question. I try to find some clue form chrome V8 source code. here is the V8 loop peeling code:

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5.4.156/src/compiler/loop-peeling.cc

I try to understand it, I consider for loop has a middle layer in the implementation. for loop will hold the increment value in middle layer.

If loop use let to declare "i", V8 will declare a new variable i for every loop iterations, copy value of middle layer increment variable to that new declared "i", then put it to loop body scope;

If loop use var to declare "i", V8 will only put the middle layer increment value reference to the loop body scope. It will decrease the performance overhead of loop iteration.

Sorry for my pool english. There is a graph in the v8 source code, it will show you the mechanism.