# Pure JavaScript - for loop works with elements[0] but not with elements[i]

Tags: javascript, loops

My simplified code, which should add an EventListener to each b element within my navigation, looks like this:

```js
function openSubNavs2()
{
 var allToggleBs = document.querySelector('ul#nav').getElementsByTagName('b');
 for (var i=0; i<allToggleBs.length; i++)
 {
  var toggleB = allToggleBs[i];
  toggleB.addEventListener('click', function()
  {
   toggleB.className = 'show';
  });
 }
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {openSubNavs2();});
```

but the EventListener 'click' is not created.

If I change the increasing allToggleBs[i] to a static allToggleBs[0], the first b element gets the class "show" when clicked - just as expected. The same works with allToggleBs[1] for the second b element.

So basically the b elements are found correctly, but the for loop is not working, and I can't find the reason why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript 'let' and 'var' in for-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847863/javascript-let-and-var-in-for-loops)

Comment: toggleB will not stay the same after the loop finishes. Either use `event.target` or `this` to refer to the clicked <b> tag instead of the variabel toggleB. YOu could also just add One click event to the nav instead of a click per <b> tag and then use event.target to have One event to handle All cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use anonymous function if you need es3 support:

```
function openSubNavs2()
{
    var allToggleBs = document.querySelector('ul#nav').getElementsByTagName('b');
    for (var i=0; i<allToggleBs.length; i++)
    {
        (function(toggleB) {
            toggleB.addEventListener('click', function() {
                toggleB.className = 'show';
            });
        })(allToggleBs[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: While let instead of var (see other posts) is useful, it didn't solve the problem. Your solution does.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` which will create individual scope.

```
for (let i=0; i<allToggleBs.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are lossing the context of `i`. You could declare the i var with `let` instead of `var`. Or still using ES5, wrapping `i` in a closure (so there, `i` won't change its value):

```
function openSubNavs2()
{
    var allToggleBs = document.querySelector('ul#nav').getElementsByTagName('b');
    for (var i=0; i<allToggleBs.length; i++)
    {
        (function(i) {
            var toggleB = allToggleBs[i];
            toggleB.addEventListener('click', function()
            {
                toggleB.className = 'show';
            });
        })(i);

    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {openSubNavs2();});
```

Comment: While let instead of var (see other posts) is useful, it didn't solve the problem. Your solution does, I just chose the other one for its support of some older browsers (while otherwise doing the same).

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable with `let` rather than `var` .You can use

```
for (let i=0; i<allToggleBs.length; i++)
```