# Variable becoming undefined in Promise function

Tags: arrays, node.js, promise

I have an array (`targets`) in global scope, the values of which I am passing to an external function [third party library, `externalConverter`] that does some text conversion. The values of this array are being passed in to the `convert` function and the conversion is happening fine.

```
const targets = [‘box’, ’box1’, ’box2’, ’box3’]

for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; ++i) {
    console.log(targets[i]); // this is coming out fine
    externalConverter
        .convert(data.text, targets[I])
        .then(results => {
            data.convertedText.push({
                [targets[i]]: results[0]
            });

            //above convertedText array comes out as
            //{“undefined: ”, “nice converted text”}, ...
        })
}
```

Inside the result of the Promise, I am trying to access the `targets` values but getting `undefined` values inside the function above. I am not sure why targets is suddenly becoming `undefined`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: When are you accessing targets?  In the `.then()` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `i` will have progressed to its final value (i.e. `targets.length`) before any of the `then` callbacks have executed, and so any use of `i` as index will be out of range.

Use `let i` instead of `var i` to make separate instances of `i` that will not have this problem.

Comment: Perfect. Not super familair with Nodejs syntax but this works. A possible link to help delve more into this would be appreciated.

Comment: `to make separate instances` -- while this is technically true if you dig into the specification, it would be much clearer to a larger audience to refer to this behavior as "lexical scoping".

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, although `let` indeed has lexical (and thus block) scope, that aspect does not not convey the notion that the loop will *not* use a single version of that variable (with block scope) that is being incremented.

Comment: @Cipher, there are many articles discussing this. For instance [this](http://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/)

Comment: @trincot [I'm aware of how `let` works in a `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793317/1541563). And yes, "lexical scoping" does include this behavior.

Comment: Just to add that this behaviour (new instances / bindings) is quite specific to the `for` loop. It is defined in the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation). When you think of it, it is quite advanced that `i++` reads the value from the current binding and the new binding gets the new value. Lexical scoping alone does not convey these mechanics.