# Improve performance for this method to flatten arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, internet-explorer

I am developing a large javascript application and unsurprisingly in IE11 it really struggles (Chrome = 8 secs, nodejs= 8 secs, IE11 = 35 secs).

So I did some profiling and found that this method is my time sink. I have already made all the changes I could think of - is there any other performance improvement modification I can put in place?

```
const flatten = function(arr, result) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return [arr];
  }

  if(!result){
    result = [];
  }

  for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
      const value = arr[i];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        flatten(value, result);
      } 
      else {
        result.push(value);
      }
  }

  return result;
  };
```

The method gets called lots of times, with smallish arrays (up to 10 string items, no more than 2 level deep).

Comment: Some JavaScript engines do `array.push(n)` faster than `array[array.length] = n`, others it's the other way around. You might check which is true for IE and use the one it finds faster.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thank you for your comment. `push()` seems quicker in all of them (IE, Chrome and nodejs)...

Comment: Okay. (That Chrome and Node.js are the same isn't a surprise -- they use the same JavaScript engine, V8.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the `if (!result)` and `Array.isArray(value)` checks repeatedly should be avoided. I'd go for

```
function flatten(arr, result = []) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      flatten(arr[i], result);
    }
  } else {
    result.push(arr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

for simplicity and if the compiler doesn't optimise this enough by inlining and recognising loop patterns, I'd also try

```
function flatten(val) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) // omit this check if you know that `flatten` is called with arrays only
    return flattenOnto(val, []);
  else
    return [val];
}
function flattenOnto(arr, result) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var val = arr[i];
    if (Array.isArray(val))
      flattenOnto(val, result);
    else
      result.push(val);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I also used normal `var` instead of `let` because [it had been known to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37792934/1048572), dunno whether that has changed by now.

If, as you say, you also know that your arrays have a limited depth, you might even want to try to inline the recursive calls and spell it out to

```
function flatten(val) {
  if (!Array.isArray(val)) return [val]; // omit this check if you can
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, ilen = arr.length; i < ilen; i++) {
    var val = arr[i];
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      for (var j = 0, jlen = val.length; j < jlen; j++) {
        // as deep as you need it
        result.push(val[j]);
      }
    } else {
      result.push(val);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If trying to eke out every last bit of performance, may be worth caching `Array.isArray` to a local.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first snippet provided (with default parameter - `result = []`) is how I had it originally, however `browserify`\`babelify` changes it to use a loop (as IE11 does not support default parameters) and it really did kill my performance... I will try with 2 methods as you suggested...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia If you are using a transpiler, you probably should write performance-sensitive code in plain ES5 to have exact control over the code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good idea, though I really would have expected browsers to have optimised that by now.

Comment: @Bergi - using the double method did help... Thank you.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, [doesn't seem to make much difference](https://jsperf.com/caching-array-isarray) (though it does make a small difference on IE11, which is the problematic one for the OP, so...).

Comment: Bergi + @T.J.Crowder - thank you. 23% quicker with your suggestions: https://jsperf.com/flattenvflatten

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Have you also profiled it in your real application? Only testing with real values can show the benefits.

Comment: @Bergi - yes, unfortunately in the application I am not seeing much of a performance increase... But it is a little bit better, nevertheless...

Answer (score -1):

The way you use recursion looks a bit odd to me: you're both returning the array and mutating a parameter depending on the depth level. You also have duplicated `Array.isArray(array)` calls. I think this code can be quite simplified, for example to something like the following (no parameter mutation as you can see):

```js
const flatten = (array) => Array.isArray(array)
  ? array.reduce((accumulated, value) => accumulated.concat(flatten(value)), [])
  : [array];
```

Not sure performances will be that improved though to be honest, but it looks more elegant in my opinion - [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) is your friend!

Comment: Creating and throwing away lots of intermediate arrays with `concat` is not going to improve time performance.

Comment: @sp00m - i gave you a +1 for trying to help, but jsPerf is your friend too... this is really killing performance...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Yeah, well, just wanted to share this tool with you in case you wanted to benchmark the solutions you received ;)