# How scope works in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, scope

When I created 5 buttons in a loop and click the value of i is always 6

```js
function createButtons() {
   for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
     var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
     button.innerHTML = 'Button ' + i;
     (function(num) {
       button.onclick = function() {
          alert('This is button ' + num);
       }
     })(i);
     body.appendChild(button);
   }
}
```

but when I change the scope of i to block scope(using IIFE or let keyword) it gives the right value of i. How does it working under the hood of javascript?

Comment: it works exactly as you have described (the code in the question is the latter variant, am I correct?)

Comment: Pretty simple: without the closure the value of `i` ***at the time event occurs*** is at it's maximum

Comment: I get why the problem happened I am just not able to understand how creating a block scope for "i" solves it.
does javascript create different copies of "i" on each iteration when in block scope?

Comment: `i` is passed to the IIFE, which takes it as the parameter `num`, and parameters are scoped to their functions, so `num` is scoped to the IIFE.

Comment: so basically each IIFE is a different object ? @Xufox

Comment: @Shubham In this case, yes, since a new function is created each iteration of the loop. But this isn’t necessary. You could also assign the function from the IIFE to an outer variable and still call it with `i` as an argument inside the loop. This way, there’s only one function, but the behavior will be the same, because `num` is scoped to the function, not to the loop.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793317/1541563). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900289/1541563).

Answer (score 0):

I have seperated your functions into `incorrect` and `correct` one.

The `incorrect` version is what you're asking. The `correct` version is what you've already figured out but don't know why it work.

In the incorrect version, the value of `i` will always be updated to the most recent value because `i` belongs to the `createButtons` function and is shared with all `onclick` handler, and it is changing with the loop.

In the correct version, the value of `i` is given to the IIFE as `num`, and `num` belongs to the IIFE and not to `createButtons`.

Because of that, `num` is fixed because a new `num` is created for every loop thus is not shared with the other `onclick` handler.

Why? It is how **closure** works in JavaScript.

[Read this for deeper understanding on JavaScript closure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

```js
function createButtons_incorrect() {
   for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
     var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
     button.innerHTML = 'Bad ' + i;
     button.onclick = function() {
        alert('This is button ' + i);
     }
     body.appendChild(button);
   }
}

function createButtons_correct() {
   for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
     var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
     button.innerHTML = 'Good ' + i;
     (function(num){
       button.onclick = function() {
          alert('This is button ' + num);
       }
     })(i);
     body.appendChild(button);
   }
}

createButtons_incorrect();
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
createButtons_correct();
```