# Why is let not slower than var?

Tags: javascript, performance, var, let

To make an extreme sum up, [the difference between `var` and `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav) is their life within a scope.

So if we are to take the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793317/3233388):

```js
(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`i: ${i}`);
    }, i * 100);
  }
  // 5, 5, 5, 5, 5


  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`j: ${j}`);
    }, 1000 + j * 100);
  }
  // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}());
```

- `i` (declared with `var`) lives within the entire `function`
- `j` (declared with `let`) lives only within the `for` loop.

To me, this means that javascript, after each iteration, besides declaring and assigning to a variable, in the case of `let` it also needs to perform an extra step: clean up `j`

But if I'm reading [the specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) right, there's so much more:

1. In the case of `var`, these steps are performed:

> *IterationStatement : for ( Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ) Statement*
>
> 1. If the first Expression is present, then
>
>    - Let exprRef be the result of evaluating the first Expression.
>    - Let exprValue be GetValue(exprRef).
>    - ReturnIfAbrupt(exprValue).
> 2. Return ForBodyEvaluation(the second Expression, the third Expression, Statement, « », labelSet).

2. But in the case of `let`, a whopping list of 12 steps are performed, including creations of new declarative environments.

   > *IterationStatement : for ( LexicalDeclaration Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ) Statement*
   >
   > 1. Let oldEnv be the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.
   > 2. Let loopEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
   > 3. Let isConst be the result of performing IsConstantDeclaration of  > 1. LexicalDeclaration.
   > 4. Let boundNames be the BoundNames of LexicalDeclaration.
   > 5. For each element dn of boundNames do
   >
   >    - If isConst is true, then
   >
   >      - Perform loopEnv.CreateImmutableBinding(dn, true).
   >    - Else,
   >
   >      - Perform loopEnv.CreateMutableBinding(dn, false).
   >      - Assert: The above call to CreateMutableBinding will never return an abrupt completion.
   > 6. Set the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment to loopEnv.
   > 7. Let forDcl be the result of evaluating LexicalDeclaration.
   > 8. If forDcl is an abrupt completion, then
   >
   >    - Set the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
   >    - Return Completion(forDcl).
   > 9. If isConst is false, let perIterationLets be boundNames otherwise let  perIterationLets be « ».
   > 10. Let bodyResult be ForBodyEvaluation(the first Expression, the second Expression, Statement, perIterationLets, labelSet).
   > 11. Set the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
   > 12. Return Completion(bodyResult).

So why is it that when running the following test (which I took from [the same question I previously referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37792934/3233388)) , `var` performs slower than `let`, and not vice versa, as I'm expecting?

```js
(function() {
  let varTime = performance.now()
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
  varTime = performance.now() - varTime;
  console.log('var', varTime)


  let letTime = performance.now()
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
  letTime = performance.now() - letTime;
  console.log('let', letTime)
}).call({});
```

```
TEST 1
var: 147.500ms
let: 138.200ms

TEST 2
var: 141.600ms
let: 127.100ms

TEST 3
var: 147.600ms
let: 122.200ms
```

Comment: it's not slower, because it's faster - the "internal workings" of the javascript engine are irrelevant

Comment: Your snippet looks inconclusive for me on Chrome. They both perform at similar speeds, either may be faster than the other, moderate margin of error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a performance difference between 'let' and 'var' in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467642/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-let-and-var-in-javascript)

Comment: @CertainPerformance out of 5 runs indeed `let` performs slower **in one** run

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. I'm not asking if there is a performance difference, I know there is one. I'm asking why

Comment: Just ran 10, `let` was slower in 7/10 tests. There's almost certainly a performance difference because they're not doing the exact same thing, but which way it goes does not yet seem conclusive based on what's seen here. (you might use `performance.now` rather than console time)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I switched to `performance.now` and see the same results as outlined in the question. What OS & browser & browser version are you using?

Comment: Implementation details are hard to reason about if we don’t dive deep into the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed with @Derek 朕會功夫 that it is really hard to reason without diving down into the implementation.

But, you might have missed the some of the steps in case of `var`:

In the case of `var`, there are actually ***more*** steps performed:

> *IterationStatement : for ( Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ) Statement*
>
> 1. If the first Expression is present, then
>
>    - Let exprRef be the result of evaluating the first Expression.
>    - Let exprValue be **GetValue**(exprRef).
>    - - ReturnIfAbrupt(V).
>    - - If Type(V) is not Reference, return V.
>    - - Let base be GetBase(V).
>    - - If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a ReferenceError exception.
>    - - If IsPropertyReference(V), then
>    - - - If HasPrimitiveBase(V) is true, then
>    - - - - Assert: In this case, base will never be null or undefined.
>    - - - - Let base be ToObject(base).
>    - - - Return base.[[Get]](GetReferencedName(V), GetThisValue(V)).
>    - - Else base must be an Environment Record,
>    - - - Return base.GetBindingValue(GetReferencedName(V), IsStrictReference(V)) (see 8.1.1).
>    - ReturnIfAbrupt(exprValue).
> 2. Return ForBodyEvaluation(the second Expression, the third Expression, Statement, « », labelSet).

The ***slightly*** additional processing could be from [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue).